# Variables changing that should be unaffected (Memory overflow?)

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I've been wrestling with an issue for hours now, and am at my wit's end.

Effectively, I have functions that take in a number of variables, and outputs others. You know, pretty standard stuff.

The problem is that one of my variables is not changed, yet it becomes messed up. I can only assume that there is a memory overflow into its space somewhere, but I cannot figure out where, why or how.

A highly simplified code is provided below (The full version is around 300 lines, and should calculate points and derivatives of a spline surface 'NURBS' thing). Apologies for the number of unused inputs in the functions (I've disabled and removed much of the code to hopefully help you guys figure out what's wrong).

When it is compiled and run, the screen output is:

```
Start Mex 40, 30
Outer Function Part 1 40, 30
Inner Function Part 1 40, 30
Inner Function Part 2 40, 30
Outer Function Part 2 817645044, 1069852220
Outer Function Part 3 817645044, 1069852220
End Mex 817645044, 1069852220
```

However the output should obviously be consistent (40, 30).

So I would be extremely grateful if someone could alert me to the reason that I'm an idiot, so I can avoid being an idiot in the future.

```
void Simple_Separate_Parametrics(double* t_frac, double* t_crd_dbl, double t_full) {
    *t_crd_dbl = floor((double)t_full);
    *t_frac = t_full - *t_crd_dbl;
}



void Calc_Point_and_XJacobian_On_SplurfaceMap(double* P, double* J, bool* Valid, unsigned long* RelCrds, double* s, double* t, double* M, double* X, unsigned long* Crds, unsigned long* GridSize) {

    double *t_frac;
    double *t_crd;

    mexPrintf("Inner Function Part 1 %u, %u\n", *(GridSize), *(GridSize+1));

    Simple_Separate_Parametrics(t_frac, t_crd, *t);

    mexPrintf("Inner Function Part 2 %u, %u\n", *(GridSize), *(GridSize+1));
}



void Points_and_XJacobian_on_Splurface(double* Points, double* Jacobian, bool* Valid, double* s, double* t, double* M, double* X, unsigned long* GridSize, size_t NumPts) {

    double* J = (double*)malloc(16*sizeof(double));
    unsigned long n, Xlen, Vpts;//m, 
    Vpts = *(GridSize+1) + 3;
    Xlen = (*(GridSize) + 3)*Vpts;


    unsigned long* Crds    = (unsigned long*)malloc(Xlen*sizeof(unsigned long));
    unsigned long* RelCrds = (unsigned long*)malloc(16*sizeof(unsigned long));

    mexPrintf("Outer Function Part 1 %u, %u\n", *(GridSize), *(GridSize+1));

    for (n = 0; n < 1; ++n) {//NumPts
        Calc_Point_and_XJacobian_On_SplurfaceMap(Points + n, J, Valid + n, RelCrds, s + n, t + n, M, X, Crds, GridSize);
        mexPrintf("Outer Function Part 2 %u, %u\n", *(GridSize), *(GridSize+1));
    }

    mexPrintf("Outer Function Part 3 %u, %u\n", *(GridSize), *(GridSize+1));

    free(J); free(Crds); free(RelCrds);
}



void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
    int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

    // [Points, Jacobian, Valid] = Function( s, t, X, GridSize)

    double *Points, *Jacobian, *s, *t, *X, *M;
    size_t NumPts, Xlen;
    unsigned long* GridSize;
    bool* Valid;

    s   = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    t   = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    X   = mxGetPr(prhs[2]);

    GridSize = (unsigned long*)malloc(2*sizeof(unsigned long));
    *(GridSize  ) = 40;
    *(GridSize+1) = 30;

    mexPrintf("Start Mex %u, %u\n", *GridSize, *(GridSize+1));
    NumPts   = mxGetN(prhs[0]);

    Xlen = mxGetM(prhs[2])*mxGetN(prhs[2]);

    M = (double*)malloc(16*sizeof(double));


    if (nlhs == 3) {
        plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix( 1, NumPts, mxREAL);
        Points = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

        plhs[1] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix( NumPts, Xlen, mxREAL);
        Jacobian = mxGetPr(plhs[1]);

        plhs[2] = mxCreateLogicalMatrix( NumPts, 1);
        Valid = (bool*)mxGetData(plhs[2]);

        Points_and_XJacobian_on_Splurface(Points, Jacobian, Valid, s, t, M, X, GridSize, NumPts);

    }

    mexPrintf("End Mex %u, %u\n", *(GridSize), *(GridSize+1));

    free(M); free(GridSize);
}
```

Comment: If you get rid of stuff like `Xlen = (*(GridSize) + 3)*Vpts;`, it gets easier. Apparently, the current pointer-ness is to much for you, and you don't have any reason to avoid more C++-like things, so... and try valgrind.

Comment: And the question is missing some (much?) relevant code. Start with a main.

Comment: @deviantfan There is no `main` in a mex function, `mexFunction` is the entry point. It's basically an so/dll that MATLAB calls. That being said, I agree with your assessment that the OP should stop being so pointer happy and try to simplify things. DavidGW, you can run mex functions under a debugger, you might want to give that a try.

Comment: `mexFunction` is MATLAB's equivalent to `main()`

Comment: I think this is a fair question and doesn't deserve the close vote. Memory seems to be unintentionally overwritten. OP: I ran the function with s=t=X=rand(40,30); and I got output of 40,30 right to the end, so you need to provide some idea of the inputs. We don't want a huge dump, so either get it to fail with something like ones or zeros, or reduce the matrix size to 3x3 or less.

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far. In terms of the over pointerisation, I've deleted the 'Xlen = (*(GridSize) + 3)*Vpts;' line, and am feeding in the Xlen value from the main mexFunction. I've also separated GridSize into two non-pointered long ints.

Unfortunately, now the code completely kills Matlab when run, so I'll have to get it running before I can add much more that will help.

Comment: Deviantfan: This is not my first mex file, I have written over a dozen heavily pointered mex files before, so although I'm sure it's a pointer problem, I'm not completely new to pointers. Also, most of the pointers that are used are for large vectors of variable length, so they can't really be removed.

Comment: Ramashalanka: Thanks for your time in trying to run the code. As I have mentioned, I've broken my version of the code in trying to fix it, however "s" and "t" will range between zero and GridSize, not zero and one. When it runs, I'll repost the code, hopefully with inputs that make it not work.

Comment: POSSIBLE ANSWER: After completely tearing apart my code trying to get it running again, I think I've finally figured out what the problem is. And it's because I'm an idiot (or because I thought C++ was slightly smarter than it is...). If you note, I'm writing to 't_frac' and 't_crd_dbl' without malloccing them a single double of memory. I guess I'll try either malloccing them their memory, or pass the addresses of non-pointers into functions, instead of using pointers here. Assuming I can reassemble my nuked code... :(

Comment: Why won't you return a `std::pair` or `boost::tuple` or a simple struct from `Simple_Separate_Parametrics`, instead of pushing outputs via pointers? Why do you pass so much via pointers, not references? What about const-correctness? Why do you have functions that take a bazillion parameters instead of a structure (or a tuple)? Why no RAII? Why do you `malloc` a simple array of 16 doubles (J)?  This reads like C, not C++. Don't write C when you got a C++ compiler. Don't use naked pointers to own data, use `std::unique_ptr`, but prefer values on stack for small fixed arrays. Uurgh!

Comment: `Also, most of the pointers that are used are for large vectors of variable length, so they can't really be removed.` etc.etc.: That's wrong. As KubaOber said too, you don't need any raw pointer and malloc here.

Answer (score 1):

The mex API, even though available from C++, is really a C API and its direct use makes one's code look like C code. This is not a good place to be in.

So, let's write the code first assuming that nice C++11 mex array wrappers exist.

We start with the parameters to the function. Let's say that `DoubleArray` and `LogicalArray` will represent the arrays of a given type and have constructors that initialize them from rhs parameters, or create new ones for lhs parameters. The arrays are simply handles to underlying matlab data, and represent a logical pointer. They would be incrementable to offset their position in relation to underlying data.

We should not use C-style fixed-size arrays, instead using the `std::array` type.

```
struct Params {
   DoubleArray s, t, X, inGridSize;
   size_t NumPts;
   std::array<size_t, 2> GridSize;
   DoubleArray Points, Jacobian;
   LogicalArray Valid;
   std::array<double, 16> M;

   Params(mxArray * plhs[], const mxArray * prhs[]) :
      s(prhs, 0),
      t(prhs, 1),
      X(prhs, 2),
      inGridSize(prhs, 3),
      NumPts(s.size()),
      Points(1, NumPts, plhs, 0),
      Jacobian(NumPts, X.size(), plhs, 1),
      Valid(NumPts, 1, plhs, 2)
   {
      std::copy(inGridSize.begin(), inGridSize.end(), GridSize.begin());
   }
};
```

These parameters can then be passed to various functions. They can be copied if we wish to modify any of the array positions.

This is pretty noncontroversial, although one could argue that perhaps the `inGridSize` is not necessary and we should initialize the `GridSize` from a temporary `DoubleArray`.

The additional parameters to the calculation of an individual point can be similarly wrapped in a structure:

```
struct PointParams {
   unsigned int Vpts;
   unsigned int Xlen;
   std::array<double, 16> J;
   std::vector<unsigned int> Crds { Xlen };
   std::array<unsigned int, 16> RelCrds;

   PointParams(const Params & p) :
      Vpts(p.GridSize[1] + 3),
      Xlen((p.GridSize[0] + 3)*Vpts)
   {}
};
```

Finally, the `Simple_Separate_Parametrics` function calculates a result of `Parametrics` type:

```
struct Parametrics {
   double t_crd_dbl, t_frac;
};

Parametrics Simple_Separate_Parametrics(double t_full) {
   Parametrics p;
   p.t_crd_dbl = floor(t_full);
   p.t_frac = t_full - p.t_crd_dbl;
   return p;
}
```

The `Calc_Point_...` takes a reference to `Params` and `PointParams`:

```
void Calc_Point_and_XJacobian_On_SplurfaceMap(Params & p, PointParams & pp) {
   mexPrintf("Begin Inner Function %u, %u\n", p.GridSize[0], p.GridSize[1]);

   auto pms = Simple_Separate_Parametrics(p.t[0]);

   mexPrintf("End Inner Function %u, %u\n", p.GridSize[0], p.GridSize[1]);
}
```

The `Points_and_XJacobian_...` takes its parameters by value, copying them so that the array pointers can be modified (incremented) within the loop. Since `p` changes in the loop, each iteration we generate a new `PointParams` instance based on `p`.

```
void Points_and_XJacobian_on_Splurface(Params p) {
   mexPrintf("Begin Outer Function %u, %u\n", p.GridSize[0], p.GridSize[1]);

   for (unsigned int n = 0; n < 1; ++n) {//NumPts
      PointParams pp(p);
      Calc_Point_and_XJacobian_On_SplurfaceMap(p, pp);
      p.Points += 1;
      p.Valid += 1;
      p.s += 1;
      p.t += 1;
   }

   mexPrintf("End Outer Function %u, %u\n", p.GridSize[0], p.GridSize[1]);
}
```

The `mexFunction` checks for proper argument counts, initializes the initial `Params`, and run the worker function `Points_and_...`.

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
   // [Points, Jacobian, Valid] = Function( s, t, X, GridSize)

   if (nrhs != 4)
      mexErrMsgTxt("Need four input parameters");
   if (nlhs != 3)
      mexErrMsgTxt("Need three output parameters");
   if (mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[3]) != 2)
      mexErrMsgTxt("GridSize needs two elements");

   Params p { plhs, prhs };
   mexPrintf("Begin Mex %u, %u\n", p.GridSize[0], p.GridSize[1]);
   Points_and_XJacobian_on_Splurface(p);
   mexPrintf("End Mex %u, %u\n", p.GridSize[0], p.GridSize[1]);
}
```

You'll notice that none of this code does any explicit memory allocations.

So, how do we implement the magic sauce? Through a generic `MxArray` class, parametrized by a value-type-specific `Traits` specialization. It of course can be reused in any mex file.

The array type acts like a C array that knows its bounds. You could easily add bounds checking in the implementation of `operator[]`. You can also add an offset to the array, shifting the position of the element at 0 index. The `size()` always returns the number of elements available from the 0 index onward. As you add a positive offset, the `size()` decreases. Adding a negative offset will increase the `size()`. The cumulative offset must not be below zero, or the behavior is undefined.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/mex-32490874

#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

template <typename T> struct Traits;

template <typename T, class Tr = Traits<T>> class MxArray {
   const mxArray * m_data;
   T * m_ptr;
public:
   typedef T * iterator;
   typedef const T * const_iterator;
   MxArray(const mxArray * data[], int index) :
      m_data(Tr::check(data, index)),
      m_ptr(Tr::ptr(m_data))
   {}
   MxArray(int n, int m, mxArray * out[], index) :
      m_data(out[index] = Tr::create(n, m)),
      m_ptr(Tr::ptr(out[index]))
   {}
   size_t size() const { return mxGetNumberOfElements(m_data) - offset(); }
   int n_dims() const { return mxGetNumberOfDimensions(m_data); }
   int dim(int i) const { return mxGetDimensions(m_data)[i]; }
   inline ptrdiff_t offset() const { return m_ptr - Tr::ptr(m_data); }
   T operator[](ptrdiff_t i) const { return m_ptr[i]; }
   T & operator[](ptrdiff_t i) { return m_ptr[i]; }
   MxArray & operator+=(ptrdiff_t offset) {
      m_ptr += offset;
      return *this;
   }
   friend MxArray operator+(MxArray lhs, ptrdiff_t offset) {
      return lhs += offset;
   }
   void resetOffset() { m_ptr = Tr::ptr(m_data); }
   iterator begin() { return m_ptr; }
   iterator end() { return m_ptr + size(); }
   const_iterator begin() const { return m_ptr; }
   const_iterator end() const { return m_ptr + size(); }
};
```

The traits for `double` and `mxLogical` (*not `bool`!*) types implement a type check and forward the functionality to relevant mex APIs.

```
const char kMsgId[] = "SO:MexExample";

template <> struct Traits<double> {
   static const mxArray * check(const mxArray * data[], int index) {
      if (! mxIsDouble(data[index]))
         mexErrMsgIdAndTxt(kMsgId, "Expected real type for input parameter #%d", index);
      return data[index];
   }
   static double * ptr(const mxArray * data) {
      return mxGetPr(data);
   }
   static mxArray * create(int n, int m) {
      return mxCreateDoubleMatrix(n, m, mxREAL);
   }
};

template <> struct Traits<mxLogical> {
   static const mxArray * check(const mxArray * data[], int index) {
      if (! mxIsLogical(data[index]))
         mexErrMsgIdAndTxt(kMsgId, "Expected logical type for input parameter #%d", index);
      return data[index];
   }
   static mxLogical * ptr(const mxArray * data) {
      return mxGetLogicals(data);
   }
   static mxArray * create(int n, int m) {
      return mxCreateLogicalMatrix(n, m);
   }
};
```

Finally, the `DoubleArray` and `LogicalArray` are simple type aliases that parametrize `MxArray` for the needed type.

```
typedef MxArray<double> DoubleArray;
typedef MxArray<mxLogical> LogicalArray;
```

It is undefined behavior to address `mxLogical` data as if it was `bool` data, but it's OK to cast between a single `mxLogical` value and `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason issues were being caused was through not using a malloc call after declaring a pointer:

```
double* Variable;
*Variable = 0.0;
Function_that_Calculates_Variable( Variable );
```

This caused either crashes, or memory overruns. I didn't realise/forgot you had to malloc a pointer to a single value. I therefore replaced it with:

```
double Variable;
Variable = 0.0;
Function_that_Calculates_Variable( &Variable );
```

which does the same thing, except does not require a malloc call and associated free, while still allowing multiple outputs in this form from the function.

Problem solved! (After far more hours of debugging than I care to admit :P)

Comment: Problem is not "solved" in that the code is still a horrible mess. It should be shorter, easier to read, and much harder to allow you to make such mistakes by design. This is at best bad C code. C-style "out arguments" via pointers are gut-wrenching. A `Function_that_Calculates_Variable` should return the variable (or a pair/tuple/struct of them) by value. Only if you are to modify arrays passed from matlab's side you're forced to scribble over data passed by pointers, and even then you should wrap them up for safe consumption from C++.

Comment: Please describe the mathematical operation you wish to carry out in the question itself (edit the question). IWhat is a splurface, and a splurface map? What would you like the code to do? I'd like to flesh out the example to actually do something useful. Could you describe what the `s, t, X` parameters are, etc.?